"Django: OperationalError - Could not translate host name 'postgres.railway.internal' to address"
I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect my Django application to a PostgreSQL database hosted on Railway. The error I'm getting is:
"Django: OperationalError - Could not translate host name 'postgres.railway.internal' to address"`

I've double-checked that the hostname and database credentials are correct. What could be causing this hostname resolution issue, and how can I resolve it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my settings.py configuration:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'railway',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'postgres.railway.internal',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


https://docs.railway.app/guides/postgresql#connect, host is as error states wrong and should be set to proper env variable

I solved the issue using dj-database-url; this is how I configured it.
First import this in your setting.py:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import dj_database_url

also include this
DATABASES = {
`'default':` `dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('Postgres.DATABASE_URL'),conn_max_age=1800)`
}

Create a .env file to store your database URL credentials. It should look something like this:
Postgres.DATABASE_URL=Your DATABASE_URL

